# $ (0,1)$ is compact w.r.t a metric which induces the usual topology on $\Bbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Which of the following is true?
>
> 1. $ (0,1)$ is complete w.r.t a metric which induces the usual topology on $\Bbb R$.
> 2. $ (0,1)$ is compact w.r.t a metric which induces the usual topology on $\Bbb R$.

1. True. Since $(0,1)$ and $\Bbb R$ have the same cardinality  hence there exists a bijective function  $f:(0,1)\to \Bbb R$. Let's define a metric $d_1$ on $(0,1)$ by $d_1(x,y)=\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|$ which defines a isometry.

Now since $\Bbb R$ is complete so will be $(0,1)$.

2. False since in order to be compact $(0,1)$ must be closed in the usual topology which will never be.

Please check my answers  and give your feedback.

Comment: Hmmm.  I can see your reasoning for #1, but then again there are Cauchy sequences in $(0, 1)$ that don't converge - e.g. $a_n = 1-1/n$.  I don't know if I'm correct in my thinking, but if so, it's interesting that completeness isn't preserved under homeomorphism.  You are correct about #2.  In addition to appealing to Heine-Borel, one can also note that the open cover $(1/n, 1 \! - \! 1/n)$ has no finite subcover.

Comment: I would assume that in these questions, the metric is supposed to be a metric on all of $\mathbb{R}$, not just a metric on $(0,1)$ (otherwise, what does "which induces the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$" mean?).